# Should Reformed and Baptist require seperate questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question [Acording to Reformed and Baptist theology why doesn't Satan surrender?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54106/acording-to-reformed-and-baptist-theology-why-doesnt-satan-surrender?noredirect=1#comment150851_54106) asks for either a Reformed or Baptist position on this subject. Many Baptist believe in freewill, such as Arminian Baptist. Should this question be split to accommodate whether Satan has freewill or not?

Comment: We were discussing this in comments and I do not know enough to be able to provide a solid recommendation.  If the tenets of Reformed teaching and Baptist teaching are significantly different regarding Satan, then perhaps it needs to be one question for each.  FWIW, Caleb and Lee have both seen it (per the edit history and comments), and did not raise a flag.  So did a few others.

Comment: Actually he says "the Reformed and Baptist viewpoint."  *Viewpoint* singular.  "Reformed Baptist" is the normal way to describe what I think he means, so it's not crystal clear, but that's how I understood it.

Comment: ... But looking at the edit history that may be an incorrect interpretation.  Good question!